# Remove repeated rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "TABLE_A","TABLE_B"

```
     TABLE_A                          TABLE_A
+=======================+        +=======+===============+
| GLID  |      DATE     |        |  TRID |    DATE       |
+=======+===============+        +=======+===============+
| 1     |   13-12-2017  |        |    1  |    13-12-2017 |
| 2     |   13-12-2017  |        |       |               |
| 3     |   13-12-2017  |        |       |               |
| 4     |   13-12-2017  |        |       |               |
| 5     |   14-12-2017  |        |       |               |
+=======+===============+        +=======+===============+
```

When we execute a query `select TABLE_A.GLID,TABLE_A.DATE,TABLE_B.TRID,TABLE_B.DATE FROM TABLE_A.TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.DATE=TABLE.B.DATE;` i got the result as

```
+=======================+=======+===============+
| GLID  |      DATE     |  TRID |    DATE       |
+=======+===============+=======+===============+
| 1     |   13-12-2017  |    1  |    13-12-2017 |
| 2     |   13-12-2017  |    1  |    13-12-2017 |
| 3     |   13-12-2017  |    1  |    13-12-2017 |
| 4     |   13-12-2017  |    1  |    13-12-2017 |
=================================================
```

How can i remove the repetetion of rows from the second column and make it null[image: repeated rows]

Comment: This is better handled in your application code. SQL is not suitable for such kind of manipulation

Comment: Or, don't try and use SQL as a reporting tool. Instead use a a reporting tool that will enable you to do such formatting of groups easily? maybe interesting? http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/slideshows/top-10-mysql-reporting-tools.html